# Is there a difference between $S_n$ and $V_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, soft-question

$$S_n=10+10+10+...$$

$$V_n=22-12+42-32+62-52+...$$

Do they represent the same series ?

Comment: How do you define these series? (None of the two is convergent, in the standard sense.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the series are divergent infinite series. They can be made to look similar by some easy manipulation.

But can they be called the same series?

**No**, they do not represent the same series *since the terms of the sequences are not the same*.

> $$S_n=10+10+10+ \ldots$$ $$V_n=22-12+42-32+62-52+\ldots$$

Note that $S_1 \not = V_1$ , $S_2 \not = V_2$ and in general, $S_n \not = V_n$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2):

They do not represent the same series since $a_n \ne b_n$
Even if their sums existed and were the same, that does not matter they are the same series.

Comment: I am not sure why this is downvoted, it's true. Think even about their partial sums, they are not the same for every $n$. For that to be true, the respective members need to coincide.

Comment: Only for this reason, I never answer such questions. Some users here just misuse their power of down-voting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are different! For any $n \in \mathbf {N}$, one has $S_n = V_{2n}$. For $V_{2n - 1}$ we have $$V_{2n - 1} = 20 n + 2.$$